# Why does Mercurial think my SQL files are binary?

Tags: sql-server, mercurial

I just scripted out my SQL Server stored procs, table definitions, etc using SQL Server Management Studio, and tried to add them to my Mercurial source control repository.  They got added just fine, but now when I change and diff them, Mercurial calls them "binary files" and doesn't give me a proper unified diff.

I thought the encoding might be a problem, so I tried regenerating the scripts and specifying ANSI for the text file output, but I get the same behavior. I can view them just fine in notepad without any odd-looking characters showing up.  Why does Mercurial think these files are binary?

Otherwise, if someone can recommend a good tool for scripting out a SQL Server database that might not cause this issue, that might work, too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've run into this problem because SQL Server Management Studio saves the files as Unicode.  The first two bytes (most of the time) of a Unicode text file define the encoding.  Most newer text editors (e.g. Notepad) handle this transparently.

The first two bytes are probably where your problem is.  They may look like ÿþ.  Or FF FE in hex.

On the "Save" button on the Save dialog is a pick list.  Choose "Save with Encoding..." and select "US-ASCII-Codepage20127".  I believe this setting is sticky and will remain for future saves.

Comment: To be clear, it's not Unicode that's the issue.  It's UTF-16, which has embedded nulls.  UTF-8 does not, unless you actually use U+0000 (which a SQL file generally would not).

Comment: It is good to know why hg thinks it is binary, but it will be better to find a fix for mercurial to force it to change its mind. Re-saving all scripts is ugly workaround. The problem is in mercurial, not in the files.

Comment: The answer worked for me, but I used "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature) - Codepage 65001" instead of ASCII

Comment: And this is NOT a sticky setting, at least not in SSMS 2012. It is, however, an enormous pain in the ass.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BinaryFiles), it's considered binary iff there are null bytes in the file.  SQL files shouldn't have null bytes, so I would check that first (try looking in a hex editor).  I assume you do know you can force diff to treat it as text

Answer (score 3):

Andrew is right; it's a NUL byte somewhere (my guess would be a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start inserted by a rude editor tool).  Don't worry about it though, unlike SVN or CVS Mercurial doesn't handle binary vs. text differently at all.  It *displays* them different when you do 'hg log', but they're not handled at all differently.

Upcoming mercurial releases special case BOMs and don't let them trigger the "user probably doesn't want to see a diff of this on console" behavior.

Comment: We actually came to the conclusion that we cannot handle UTF-16 or UTF-32 in a consistent way that will work under Windows. Please see: http://mercurial.markmail.org/thread/lsoj7dj47mx6xoyx  The patch format just cannot handle non-ASCII characters :-/ Suggestions welcome (on the mailinglist, please).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when editing a file of stored procedures from SQL Server on linux and using git.  Git thought it was a binary file because the file from SQL Server was UTF-16, and therefore contained NULs.  My fix for this was emacs, which lets you change the encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but I came up with a script to batch save the *.sql files into UTF-8.

Full answer is posted in another thread on StackOverflow, so I'll just post the link here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9743360/336079.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and decided to use a tool found at http://www.devio.at/index.php/smoscript to help me solve the problem. I scripted SMOscript by placing the following in a `cmd` file.

```
rd /s /q [the scripts folder]
"C:\Program Files\devio IT Services\SMOscript\smoscript.exe" -s [server] -d [database] -F [the scripts folder] -U
```

The idea is to remove the old folder so that any objects deleted from the database will be deleted from source control. This also saves files as UTF8 without any date/time stamping, so they work great in version control.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for SQL Server Management Studio is to change the default SQL template file to UTF-8 (or whatever encoding you want), which will affect all future saves through SSMS.

- Open in Notepad (as administrator): `C:\Program Files (x86)\<ssms-version>\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\SQLFile.sql`
- File > Save As
- Change "Encoding" to UTF-8 or similar
- Overwrite the original file

Credit goes to https://joehanna.com/sql-server/changing-the-default-encoding-of-sql-files-in-ssms/