# Why does TortoiseHg think Resource.h is binary?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mercurial, tortoisehg, binaryfiles

Using Visual Studio 2010.  I have a resource.h file which TortoiseHg thinks is binary so it won't display a diff for it in the commit window.  I can easily open the file in a text editor and see that it is plain text.

I saw a related question ([Why does Mercurial think my SQL files are binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366484/why-does-mercurial-think-my-sql-files-are-binary)) which suggests it has to do with file encoding.  Indeed opening the file in Notepad++ says the file is in "UCS-2 Little Endian".  How can I fix this?  I, obviously, don't want to break some Visual Studio expectation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For display purposes only, Mercurial treats all files containing NUL **bytes** as binary due to long-standing UNIX convention. This is just about always right.. except for UTF-16 (formerly known as UCS-2).. where half your file is NUL bytes!

Internally, Mercurial treats **all** files as binary all the time, so this issue is only relevant for things like whether or not we try to display diffs.

So you have two options:

- ignore it, Mercurial will work just fine
- use an encoding other than UTF-16

Some web searched for "resource.h utf-16" suggest that VS2010 will be just fine if you save this file in UTF-8 or ASCII, which should be perfectly fine choices for C source code.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/aff0f96d-16e3-4801-a7a2-5032803c8d83

Comment: As described in that thread, from within Visual Studio I opened the resource.h file and went to the menu File->Advanced Save Options and chose the encoding "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001". After two commits I can now see a proper diff.

Comment: Correction, upon choosing "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001" after editing in the resource editor Visual Studio complains about the file not being a Visual Studio file.  Instead I used "US-ASCII" (as described in the linked thread in this answer).  Maybe the problem was the UTF-8 signature?  There is an option for no signature, but for now I'm considering the problem solved.

Comment: Always prefer the no-signature option. The BOM (the signature in question) is a common source of problems in many programs. And as even without BOM it is relatively simple to auto-detect the difference between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 once it contains a character outside the ASCII range, it does not really add value either.

Answer (score 5):

Try explicitly converting / changing the encoding to UTF-8 / ASCII and see. You can do that from Notepad++'s `Encoding` menu ( choose Encode in UTF-8)

Visual Studio will work with the UTF-8 file just fine.

Comment: This not true for the .rc file, tested in Visual Studio 2008 and 2013. I get lots of errors like "error RC2135: file not found: 0x07" when compiling. Resource.h can be UTF-8, though.